# Download multiple rows of errors in database with the same id into xls file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am using this piece of code at the moment to download the errors stored in columns 'data' and 'data2' residing in the fildemo table in sql database.

```
  protected void helloGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String connectionString = DAO.GetConnectionString();
            String sqlQuery = String.Empty;


            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                sqlQuery = "select data,data2 from filedemo where id=@id";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", surgicalGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read())
                {

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dr["name"].ToString() + ".xls");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    Response.Write(dr["data"] + "\t");
                    Response.Write(dr["data2"] + "\t");
                    Response.End();

                }
            }

        }
```

I will want to pull out errors from the different rows with the same Id and store them in separate rows in the excel file. How do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Response.Write(dr["data"] + "\t\n\r");` ?

Comment: it does not seems to be working for me. nonetheless thanks! :)

Comment: It does implicitly provide an answer to the question. It also works on my machine (although \r\n is better than \n\r). To the OP, you'll need to share what exactly isn't working to get a better answer.